# How do I determine if a backup occurred on my Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup

I'm having to do sys admin work, without the training.  (Long story.)  We've got a tape drive in one of our Windows 2003 R2 servers.  The former sys admin setup a backup job in the Windows Backup and Restore utility, which we've been running, by hand, for a long time.  Last week I couldn't be there to fire off the backup job, so I tried to schedule it within the Backup and Restore utility, and I thought that I had.  How do I determine that the job ran?  I got onto the server, got into the event viewer, looked at Applications for the relevant time period, but didn't see anything.  Does that mean it didn't work?  Or do I have to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NTBackup logs can be found here (this is, of course, if your old sysadmin hasn't set it up to save elsewhere):

> C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data

I do however agree with Oliver's answer. To truly understand if a backup has worked, you must restore a file from that backup (This will definitely save your bacon if you ever had to restore a server from scratch).

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked the directory you referenced and found that it didn't backup anything.  I'll just start the backup manually.

Answer (score 4):

Restore a file from the backup.